# WiX - how to modularise by features?

Tags: wix, modularity

I want to make a MSI installation using WiX and EmbeddedGUI. I really want to make it highly modular - ie the main MSI will contain only the basic files (the required ones), and all other features will be split into separate MSI files, which will be downloaded from internet if not present on hard drive and installed only if selected in my EmbeddedGUI.

But I am totally new to WiX, and I can't find a way to actually how to make that modules? MS Office and MS Visual Studio seems to be using this scheme, by using the modules which it downloads over internet and installs them in case of need - something like this:
[image: Visual Studio Installer]

It seems that Fragments is mostly like "static libraries", not "dynamic libraries" which would be more useful in such a situation. There is also the Chaining mechanism, but I'm not sure I will be able to bundle the features as the same application (only one entry in "Install/Delete" window) because it seems to be calling external MSIs completely separately (more like invoking "separate exes" instead of loading "dynamic libraries").

So, what is the way to go for making a highly modular setup package with WiX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a bundle (chain). The Burn engine, which manages bundles, will show only the bundle in Add/Remove Programs and can download any packages that aren't already present -- for example, using the [MsiPackage/@DownloadURL attribute](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html).

Comment: Thanks! Seems like I will look in bundles and chaining more carefully after all. They can be conditional based on selected features then?

Comment: If I understood well, I don't need to use the EmbeddedUI, but instead create my own Bootstrap Application, which will actually manage the installation? Setting variables, and based on them selecting the needed packages via InstallCondition?